# Filter array of object by nested array of object boolean property

Tags: javascript

```
const Person = [
    {
        firstname: "john",
        lastname: "doe",
        items: [
            {
                visible: true,
                foo: "bar"
            },
            {
                visible: false,
                foo: "bar"
            }
        ]
    },
        {
        firstname: "jane",
        lastname: "doe",
        items: [
            {
                visible: false,
                foo: "bar"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        firstname: "john",
        lastname: "adam",
        items: [
            {
                visible: true,
                foo: "bar"
            },
            {
                visible: false,
                foo: "bar"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

In the above array of `Person` objects, i have an array of `items` objects that has a property `visible`. I'm trying to filter `Person` object based on the `visible` field: `true` or `false`. The filtered Person object's items array of object will only hold true or false as well. How can I achieve this?

I have tried:

I tried:

```
const filteredPerson = Person.filter(person => {
    person.items.filter(item => item.visible === true)
})
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please add your input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single `filter()` is enough here. Since the *visible* property in *item* is at 0 index you can use the that index:

```js
const Person = [{firstname: "john",lastname: "doe",items: [{visible: true,foo: "bar"}]},{firstname: "jane",lastname: "doe",items: [{visible: false,foo: "bar"}]},{firstname: "john",lastname: "adam",items: [{visible: true,foo: "bar"}]}];

const filteredPerson = Person.filter(person => person.items[0].visible)
console.log(filteredPerson);
```

If the property index is not known then you have to use `some()` inside `filter()`. You can use `map()` to return the specific property from objects in the array:

```js
const Person = [{firstname: "john",lastname: "doe",items: [{visible: true,foo: "bar"}]},{firstname: "jane",lastname: "doe",items: [{visible: false,foo: "bar"}]},{firstname: "john",lastname: "adam",items: [{visible: true,foo: "bar"}]}];

const filteredPerson = Person.filter(person => person.items.some(s =>s.visible)).map(p => ({items: p.items}));
console.log(filteredPerson);
```

Comment: What if its not on the first index?

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to only filter the items array based on `true` or `false`?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty, do you mean only to get the *item* not other property as the result?

Comment: Yup just the array of items from each Property object, but still filtered by true/false.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty, then you have to use `map()` to return only the *items*.. Updated the second answer....please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184602/discussion-between-zerodarkthirty-and-mamun).

Comment: I've updated my question with another scenario.
now items has multiple objects, each with visible either true or false.
how can i filter Person now, either by true OR false?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty, What is the output you expect from the updated array?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEJjOx?editors=0011  So in this example, I want index 0's Person object's `items` array to only include `visible` true. I want it to be the same if I add true/false objects in another index's Person object.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty, why only the first index not the third index? How to differentiate those to objects?

Comment: that was just an example. regardless of what the index is, if any of them have array of `item` objects, each with different `visible` values... i want to be able to filter Person with only those items objects that are all true or all false.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty, try with `every()` instead of `some()`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const Person = [{firstname: "john",lastname: "doe",items: [{visible: true,foo: "bar"}]},{firstname: "jane",lastname: "doe",items: [{visible: false,foo: "bar"}]},{firstname: "john",lastname: "adam",items: [{visible: true,foo: "bar"}]}];
// Filters all those objects in Person array which has atleast one visible item
const result = Person.filter(v => v.items.some(o => o.visible));
console.log(result);
```

**EDIT** (Use nested Array.filter)

```js
const Person = [{firstname: "john",lastname: "doe",items: [{visible: true,foo: "bar"},{visible: false,foo: "bar"}]},{firstname: "jane",lastname: "doe",items: [{visible: false,foo: "bar"}]},{firstname: "john",lastname: "adam",items: [{visible: true,foo: "bar"},{visible: false,foo: "bar"}]}];
// Filters all those objects in Person array which has atleast one visible item
const result = Person.filter(v => {
  const filteredItems = v.items.filter(o => o.visible);
  if(filteredItems.length) { // if there is any visible item
    v.items = filteredItems;
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I've updated my question with another scenario. now items has multiple objects, each with visible either true or false. how can i filter Person now, either by true OR false?

Comment: when you have this scenario, `some` doesn't filter the items array in the filtered Person array that gets returned.

Comment: This only works for `true` items. how do i do it for `false`?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty - Do you want to filter only those values where all the items in an object are either true or false?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty - Which also means that in the above example posted, the resulting array will have only 1 element with item having only 1 entry. As the other 2 elements in array will be ignored as in each of the items array there is a mixture of true and false entries